PDF rendering issue involving PowerPoint boxes
I use PowerPoint to make a custom image by adding text boxes over an existing image. The fill of the text boxes is white and there is either no outline or white outline. There is no issue with the image as I see it on the screen in PowerPoint.
When I include the image in a figure using Overleaf (minimal working example code is below), the image in the preview of the PDF is also fine, there is no issue with the image as I see it in the preview of the PDF.
However, when I download the PDF from Overleaf, there is gray along the outline of the added boxes. The gray outline is also partially visible when I print the PDF. See the difference in the two images below my latex code.
In my feeble attempt at trouble shooting, the only thing I could think of was to force high resolution on the graphic, as with this stack exchange post, but that did not work.
Has anyone found a work around for this issue, or am I going to have to use screenshots or a different graphics editing approach?
Thanks all
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{centering}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{H-2K-2L-16_PlanesAndPeak_main.png}
  \end{centering}
  \caption{caption
  }
  \label{fig:label}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Here is the image as I see it in the preview

Here is the image as I see it in the downloaded PDF

Edit: here is a png of the picture when I save it from powerpoint via 'save as picture...' (rather than a screenshot of what I see)


unrelated to your question but \begin{centering}   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{H-2K-2L-16_PlanesAndPeak_main.png}   \end{centering} will not centre anything, the syntax should just be \centering

Hi! When you save the image from PowerPoint, in what format are you saving it? And specifically, are you saving it using the PowerPoint `Save as Picture' option? I have found using that option gave me issues before, so I always copy the image over to paint and save it there instead.

@simply_a_student I am using save as picture and saving as png. I tried your method with paint saving as png and it worked. Thank you

Can you share the .png?

@DavidCarlisle It will work both for images with \linewidth and for images with 0pt width :P

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz you mean it will appear to work for the 0pt ones?

@cfr yes, the visual output won't look uncentred :)

@elscan Can you export the image from powerpoint as pdf, svg or eps?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I can export as svg. However using the svg package, the minus sign gets crammed into the equals sign. I can fix that problem by using the option [inkscapeformat=png], but then the original problem returns. So far, the 'best' workaround I can see is to save as jpg from PowerPoint.

Can you print as pdf from powerpoint?
